# Angularjs bootstrap modal pop up not working

Tags: html, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have an about.html where it shows the 6 images in each column. When you click on individual profile the new pop up window should pop up (open up) which show a background info of that individual. This is just the bootstrap hard codes inside the angularjs app. I have been trying to create the angularjs modal pop up as shown:

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
           <a href="#profile-1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
           <div class="portfolio-hover">
              <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                 <p class="p-hover">my profile...</p>                           
               </div>
               </div>
                <img src="images/pic1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""> </a>
                <div class="portfolio-caption">

                    <p class="text-muted">Guitarist since 1977</p>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

This should be the content on pop up window once you click on image of the profile:

```
<modal id="profile-1">
    <div class="modal">
         <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                <div class="modal-body">
                 <img src="images/pic1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>

              <div class=" col-xs-12 col-md-9">
               <h6>consectetur adipisicing elit. </h6>

               <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                </p>
              <button ng-click="vm.closeModal('profile-1');">Close</button>
               </div>
              </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</modal>
```

I have then use this controller code based on this website:[angularjs custom modal](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/07/13/angularjs-custom-modal-example-tutorial)

```
 controller.js
          `angular.module('RouteControllers', [])
           .controller('AboutController', function($scope)  {

   function Controller(ModalService) {
       var vm = this; 
       vm.openModal = openModal;
       vm.closeModal = closeModal;

   initController();

   function initController() {
        //vm.bodyText = 'This text can be updated in modal 1';
   }         
   function openModal(id){
        ModalService.Open(id);
   } 
   function closeModal(id){
        ModalService.Close(id);
   }
}
```

I've tried few ways but I think at the moment I'm just confused. Any helpful tips would be lovely.

Comment: Since you asked for tips: you controller code in `controller.js` is not proper. As of now, I'm not sure `ModalService` is being properly injected, which would cause the rest of your code to be problematic. Try mirroring his syntax if it is causing issues.

Comment: @KreepN, thanks for pointing that out but I should include the 'ModalService' code too as I have used them but not working still. Thanks